# Update column in existing table in Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, sql-update, symfony4, symfony5.4

[I just want to update column in my existing entity class, but when I migrate to database using php bin/console ..., It's always shows table already exists or column could not be repeated ]
What should I do with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, what migration are you executing.
If you are not sure, you can delete all migrations in migrations folder
of your project.
And in your database, empty doctrine_migrations table.
Then, try to generate and execute migrations again.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the down action of the migration with:

`bin/console doctrine:migration:execute --down "name_of_the_migration"` .

Where the name of the migration is DoctrineMigrations\VersionXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Then update what you need and migrate the migration again with the new changes.